# While using an AutoFilter to exclude values, I am getting an error message

Tags: vba, excel

I have seven different values that I wish to exclude using an `AutoFilter`.

I have tried the following code, but it gives an error:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
     "<>BESTPAYMENTS", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>IGL", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria3:="<>MGBILLPAY", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria4:="<>NDPL", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria5:="<>RBPAYMENTS", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria6:="<>TABCAB", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria7:="<>TDNPAY"
```

Can someone help?

Comment: By "deselecting filter", do you mean "create a filter to exclude certain values"?

Comment: Criteria3 is MGBILLPAY,  Criteria4 is NDPL, Criteria5 is RBPAYMENTS, Criteria6 is TABCAB, Criteria7 is TDNPAY.

Comment: No, my question is what were those named parameters - I don't think they are even valid - I thought there was only `Criteria1` and `Criteria2`.

Comment: Yes, i want to exclude this value

Comment: You won't be able to just use named parameters that the method doesn't support.  I'm sure that someone else would have wanted to use more than 2 criteria in a `AutoFilter` - I'll do a search and see if I can find something - I suggest you do too (we will hopefully use different search terms and thus find an answer quicker that way).

Comment: How many different criteria do you have that **will** be selected?  And are they known in advance?  (Because it is very easy to **include** multiple values, it's just hard to **exclude** multiple values.)

Comment: I couldn't find a similar question (but my searching is never very effective, so that doesn't mean there isn't one), so I have posted an answer that should hopefully work.

Comment: I want to deselect 7 criteria from the list

Comment: But how many do you **not** want to exclude?  It is very easy to include only certain values so, if you only have a total of 12 possible values, it can easily include the 5 that you **don't** want to exclude.  But if there is 1000 that you don't want to exclude, that becomes impractical.

Comment: Exclude value is 7 out of 100, the below code takes too much time to work

Comment: What is your range set to?  Does your code include `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`?  (It took me 9 seconds to process a range containing 10000 rows, with about 9995 of those needing to be hidden.)

Comment: Another method would be to create a formula in Excel which (assuming that the column you are looking at is column L) says something like `=OR(L2="BESTPAYMENTS", L2="IGL", L2="MGBILLPAY", L2="NDPL", L2="RBPAYMENTS", L2="TABCAB", L2="TDNPAY")` and filter on that extra "helper" column.

Answer (score 2):

The `AutoFilter` method only supports two `Criteria`.

It is very easy to select multiple values for **inclusion**, e.g. by doing something like:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=12, _
            Criteria1:=Array("first_value", _
                             "another_value", _
                             "something else", _
                             "and yet another one"), _
            Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

However, it is a lot harder to **exclude** values, because of the implicit `Or` being used between elements in the array.

I believe you will need to use code similar to the following to achieve what you are after:

```
Dim r As Range
For Each r In .Columns(12).Cells
    If r.Row <> .Row Then ' to avoid processing the header row
        Select Case r.Value
            Case "BESTPAYMENTS", _
                 "IGL", _
                 "MGBILLPAY", _
                 "NDPL", _
                 "RBPAYMENTS", _
                 "TABCAB", _
                 "TDNPAY"
                r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case Else
                r.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End Select
    End If
Next
```

Unfortunately this just hides and unhides rows, rather than applying a true filter, but it is probably the best you can hope for.